# Algorithm to transform an arbitrary MIP problem into the corresponding formulation for PSO

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, optimization, linear-programming

Is there an algorithm to transform an arbitrary [Mixed Integer Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Integer_unknowns) problem into the corresponding formulation for [Particle Swarm Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_swarm_optimization)? I have found some information related to the use of penalty functions to avoid violation of constraints, but not a well defined procedure to convert the objective function and each of the constraints as required for a PSO solution.

Comment: Note that MIP is a problem formulation and PSO is a heuristic. So what you mean is that you're asking how to solve an MIP using PSO.

Comment: Suresh, I am not asking how to solve the MIP problem using PSO: I know how PSO works and I have already implemented in C and MPI parallel versions of PSO to solve other problems. What I am asking for is how to translate the MIP problem in the corresponding PSO function whose fitness must be optimized.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I have found how to do this by reading [Introduction to Mathematical Optimization: From Linear Programming to Metaheuristics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1904602827). Chapters 7 and 10 clearly explain the possibilities, essentially the penalty method and the use of Lagrange multipliers coupled with Kuhn-Tucker conditions if necessary.